# Can tesseract work with languages such as bengali? If so, with how much accuracy and what steps should I follow to implement it for bengali language?

Tags: nlp, tesseract

I want to implement an offline program which can detect bengali text from an image (white background black text). I need to know how to approach my work to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Tesseract is trained for Bengali. List of [languages supported](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#languages). You have to use language code `ben` for that. Rest of the implementation details are given [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage). Simply follow it.

Comment: with how much accuracy @rishi

Comment: There are no stats for Bengali. You will have to try it out. I would highly encourage you to add to my answer if you are able to get some stats.